# findOne() returns value from form

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf, crud, spring-thymeleaf

I'm trying to do a login and for that I'm using the findOne method in the CrudRepository. The thing is that, if the user and password in the db is "admin" and "admin" (for example), and I write in the form "admin" and whatever password, it will execute the findOne but the object it returns is an object with the username and password that I wrote in the form. Here's my code:

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/acceso", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String acceder(Model model, HttpServletRequest request, @Validated Usuario usuario,
            BindingResult result, SessionStatus status) {
        System.out.println(usuarioService.findOne(usuario.getUsuario()));
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            return "acceso";
        } else if (usuarioService.findOne(usuario.getUsuario())==null){
            model.addAttribute("error","Usuario no existente. Inténtelo de nuevo");
            return "acceso";
        } else if (usuarioService.findOne(usuario.getUsuario()).getContrasena()==usuario.getContrasena()){
            model.addAttribute("usuario",usuario);
            return "index";
        } else {
            model.addAttribute("errContra","Contraseña incorrecta, inténtelo de nuevo");
            return "acceso";
        }
    }
```

Usuario entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="usuarios")
@NamedQuery(name="Usuario.findAll", query="SELECT u FROM Usuario u")
public class Usuario implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @NotEmpty
    private String usuario;

    @NotEmpty
    private String contrasena;

    public Usuario(String usuario, String contrasena) {
        this.usuario = usuario;
        this.contrasena = contrasena;
    }

    public Usuario() {
    }

    public String getUsuario() {
        return usuario;
    }

    public void setUsuario(String usuario) {
        this.usuario = usuario;
    }

    public String getContrasena() {
        return contrasena;
    }

    public void setContrasena(String contrasena) {
        this.contrasena = contrasena;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Usuario [usuario=" + usuario + ", contrasena=" + contrasena + "]";
    }
    
}
```

Login HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Gestión de la biblioteca</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.6.4/dist/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" th:href="@{/style.css}"></link>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <h1>Inicio de sesión</h1>
            <form th:object="${usuario}" th:action="@{/acceso}" method="post">
                <label for="usuario">Nombre de usuario:</label>
                <input type="text" id="usuario" name="usuario" th:field="*{usuario}">
                <span th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('usuario')}" th:errors="*{usuario}" class="error"></span><br>
        
                <label for="contrasena">Contraseña:</label>
                <input type="password" id="contrasena" name="contrasena" th:field="*{contrasena}">
                <span th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('contrasena')}" th:errors="*{contrasena}" class="error"></span><br>
        
                <input type="submit" value="Iniciar sesion">
            <h4 th:text="${error}" class="error"></h4>
            </form>         
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I tried making a custom query but it didn't work either

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing the user data filled in the form against the one stored in the database and if they match you return the form data in controller

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "/acceso", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String acceder(Model model, HttpServletRequest request, @Validated Usuario usuario, BindingResult result, SessionStatus status) {
    System.out.println(usuarioService.findOne(usuario.getUsuario()));
    var databaseUser = usuarioService.findOne(usuario.getUsuario());
    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        return "acceso";
    } else if (databaseUser==null){
        model.addAttribute("error","Usuario no existente. Inténtelo de nuevo");
        return "acceso";
    } else if (databaseUser.getContrasena()==usuario.getContrasena()){
        model.addAttribute("usuario",databaseUser); //You where returning the form object here
        return "index";
    } else {
        model.addAttribute("errContra","Contraseña incorrecta, inténtelo de nuevo");
        return "acceso";
    }
}
```

Aside from that looking at given code my assumption would be that you'r storing plain text passwords which is a huge security flaw. I would suggest spending the time looking into the form-login that spring provides and see if you can use this. https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-login

Comment: This is only for my class so there's no problem with the password security. The thing is that the findOne should look up in the database and it doesn't. Thanks :)